# scraping website on web proxy using python

Tags: python, authentication, cookies, proxy

I am working on scraping databases that I have access to using the duke library web proxy. I encountered the issue that since the data base is accessed through a proxy server, I can't directly scrape this database as I would if the database was did not require proxy authentication.

I tried several thing:

I wrote one script that logs into the duke network (https://shib.oit.duke.edu/idp/AuthnEngine').

I then hardcode in my login data:

```
login_data = urllib.urlencode({'j_username' : 'userxx',
                           'j_password' : 'passwordxx',
                           'Submit' : 'Enter'
                           })
```

I then login:

```
resp = opener.open('https://shib.oit.duke.edu/idp/AuthnEngine', login_data)
```

and then I create a cookie jar object to hold the cookies from proxy website.

then i try to access the database with my script and it is still telling me authentication is required. I wanted to know how I can get around the authentication required for the proxy server.

If you have any suggestions please let me know.

Thank you,
Jan

Answer (score 0):

A proxy login does not store cookies but instead uses the `Proxy-Authorization` header. This header will need to be sent with every request similar to `Cookies`. The header is of the same format as regular Basic Authentication, although there are different formats possible (`Digest`, `NTLM`.) I suggest you check the headers of a normal login and copy and paste the `Proxy-Authorization` header that was sent.